# How to represent optional group with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use C# to parse out text using a regex.

I have the following text **example 1**

```
Fn.If(first condition) 
   When the first condition is valid! This is a required section
Fn.ElseIf(some second condition)
   When the second condition is valid! This is an optional section
Fn.ElseIf(third second condition)
   When the third condition is valid! This is an optional section
Fn.Else
    Catch all! This is an optional section
Fn.End
```

I want to be able to extract each section into 3 groups so the end result looks something like this

- (Group 1A): Fn.If
- (Group 1B): first condition
- (Group 1C): When the first condition is valid! This is a required section
- (Group 2A): Fn.ElseIf
- (Group 2B): second condition
- (Group 2C): When the second condition is valid! This is an optional section
- (Group 3A): Fn.ElseIf
- (Group 3B): third condition
- (Group 3C): When the third condition is valid! This is an optional section
- (Group 4A): Fn.Else
- (Group 4B): Catch all! This is an optional section
- (Group C): Fn.End

As you can see from the comments, Group 1(A/B/C) must exist along with the last group for the pattern to be valid. However, all the groups in between are optional meaning they could exists or maybe not.

In addition to the text example above, the pattern should be able to parse the following text **example 2**

```
Fn.If(first condition) 
   When first condition is valid! This is a required section
Fn.EndIf
```

or text **example 3**

```
Fn.If(first condition) 
   When first condition is valid! This is a required section
Fn.Else
    Catch all! This is an optional section
Fn.EndIf
```

I am able to do this

1. `(Fn\.If\s*)\((.+?)\)([\s\S]+)(Fn\.EndIf)` works with text example 2
2. `(Fn\.ElseIf\s*)\((.+?)\)([\s\S]+)` will return the `Fn.ElseIf(...)....` group
3. `(Fn\.Else)([\s\S]+)` will capture the `Fn.Else.....` groups

However, I am struggling to put all 3 patterns togather while idecating that line 2 can have zero or more groups, followed by one or none of line 3.

I tried the following which isn't working. To make it easier to read, I added a new line after each group for the sake of the question only.

```
(Fn\.If\s*)\((.+?)\)([\s\S]+)
((Fn\.ElseIf\s*)\((.+?)\)([\s\S]+))*
((Fn\.Else)([\s\S]+))?
(Fn\.EndIf)
```

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a Regex here? Personally I'd use separate regexes to match the `Fn....` lines and capture the text using `Substring`.

Comment: I don't have to have regex. I thought it would make it easy if I have an array of the logic

Answer (score 0):

I felt using a single monolithic Regex would make things too complicated - so here's a finite-state-machine based approach that still uses Regexes to capture each line.

```
void Main()
{
    const String input = 
@"Fn.If(first condition)
   When the first condition is valid! This is a required section
Fn.ElseIf(some second condition)
   When the second condition is valid! This is an optional section
Fn.ElseIf(third second condition)
   When the third condition is valid! This is an optional section
Fn.Else
    Catch all! This is an optional section
Fn.End  
    ";

    Regex rIf     = new Regex( @"^Fn\.If\((.+)\)\s*$" );
    Regex rElseIf = new Regex( @"^Fn\.ElseIf\((.+)\)\s*$" );
    Regex rElse   = new Regex( @"^Fn\.Else\s*$" );
    Regex rEnd    = new Regex( @"^Fn\.End\s*$" );

    String[] lines = input.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None );

    List<Statement> statements = new List<Statement>();

    String type = null;
    String condition = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    State state = State.Outside;
    foreach( String line in lines )
    {
        switch( state )
        {
        case State.Outside:

            Match mIf = rIf.Match( line );
            if( mIf.Success )
            {
                type = "Fn.If";
                condition = mIf.Groups[1].Value;

                state = State.InIf;
            }

            break;
        case State.InIf:
        case State.InElseIf:

            Match mElseIf = rElseIf.Match( line );
            if( mElseIf.Success )
            {
                statements.Add( new Statement( type, condition, sb.ToString() ) );
                sb.Length = 0;

                state = State.InElseIf;
                type = "Fn.ElseIf";
                condition = mElseIf.Groups[1].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Match mElse = rElse.Match( line );
                if( mElse.Success )
                {
                    statements.Add(new Statement(type, condition, sb.ToString()));
                    sb.Length = 0;

                    state = State.InElse;
                    type = "Fn.Else";
                    condition = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append( line );
                }
            }

            break;

        case State.InElse:

            Match mEnd = rEnd.Match(line);
            if (mEnd.Success)
            {
                statements.Add(new Statement(type, condition, sb.ToString()));
                sb.Length = 0;

                state = State.Outside;
                type = null;
                condition = null;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append( line );
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    statements.Dump();
}

class Statement
{
    public Statement( String type, String condition, String contents )
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Condition = condition;
        this.Contents = contents;
    }

    public String Type { get; }
    public String Condition { get; }
    public String Contents { get; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
enum State
{
    Outside,
    InIf,
    InElseIf,
    InElse
}
```

Running in Linqpad gives me this output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am trying to apply it to see if it works as expected. It seems to work fine with the limitation that each command (if, elseif, else) must be on a separate line. What about the case when they commands are part of a sentance? For example, `This is a Fn.If(1 == 2) LONG Fn.ElseIf(2 ==2) SHORT Fn.Else N/A Fn.End sentance and it may goes on and on.` How can I account for when the logic within a sentance or a paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable with one regex

This is a python version of the regex, but it should be translatable to C#

key is to use same capture group for all matches

`(Fn\.[A-Za-z]+[^\(\n]*)((\((.+?)\)(?<=\)))?([\s\S]*?)(?=Fn\.))?`

tested with all 3 examples

online preview:
https://regex101.com/r/VqNlMm/1

Comment: This almost does the trick. I don't understand everything about the expression so I can't freely modify it. what does `^` means in the `[^\(\n]` chunk? What does `(?<=\)` and `(?=Fn\.)` mean or do? A couple of things will not work with this pattern if one adds `(some text)` after the `Else` or if the text come directly on the same line after the `Else` for example `Fn.Else Catch all! This is an optional section Fn.End` (on the same line) or `Fn.Else(Some mistake) Catch all! This is an optional section Fn.End` or if one added multiple Else or multiple If.

Comment: `^` used inside [] is a negation. `[^\(\n]` will match everything except `(`(for cases with parameters) or `\n`(\n when there are no parameters). (?<=\)) positive look-ahead for closing bracket `)`.  (?=Fn\.) positive look-ahead for for next keyword

Comment: adding (some text) after `Else` should work, it should work with infinite number of conditions, could you edits that online regex test string to show the example that doesn't work?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/h6WA4g/1 updated with parameter after else

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MdtgVU/1 updated to work with single line Else statement